# Is there a way to utilize the display:none function on a tag to remove a full page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've got two html pages that i want to run simultaneously because websockets were introducing problems with threading and clashing of data. I thought it would be better to run both as they are both light weight web pages and just display none one when the other is needed and vice versa.

I tried to incorporate that method into the header tag in the css file but nothing seemed to happen, any advice is appreciated!

EDIT: I already have the switching code that switches between both pages, i just need to know how to incorporate the display:none function to hide, in this example, the header tag.

'''

```css
header {
    height: 53px;
    width: 53px;
    background-color: black;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 118px 244px 118px;

    padding-top: 3px;

    font-size: 45px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.headerBox {
    background-color: #4472C4;
}

.leftDrive {
    background-color: black;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
    grid-column-gap: 3px; 

    padding-inline-start: 3px;
    padding-inline-end: 4px;

}

.battery {
    background-color: #4472C4;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
}

.rightDrive {
    background-color: black;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
    grid-column-gap: 3px; 

    padding-inline-start: 4px;
    padding-inline-end: 3px;
}
```

```html
<header> 
    <div class="leftDrive">
        <div class="headerBox" id="l_motor">0</div>
        <div class="headerBox" id="l_inverter">0</div>
    </div>
    <div class="battery">
        <div class="headerBox" id="battery_1">0</div>
        <div class="headerBox" id="battery_2">0</div>
        <div class="headerBox" id="battery_3">0</div>
        <div class="headerBox" id="battery_4">0</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightDrive">
        <div class="headerBox" id="r_inverter">0</div>
        <div class="headerBox" id="r_motor">0</div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: its very unclear to me what you want to achieve.. please eleborate, what part do you want to hide, when?

Comment: @Rmaxx I want to know how to hide the header tag using the display:none function, basically hide the full thing so that i could display something else on top

Comment: Hey, kindly try to explain your question in more detail. It would help if you explained what are the two pages. But also you would need a button or something to switch the two pages.

Comment: Just put `display: none` in the `header` CSS rule instead of `display: grid`. Did you even try it?

Comment: @Pauloco I already that code setup with javascript and all that jazz, i just need to know the fundamentals of how to hide a full tag using the display:none function in css.

Comment: @Lennholm Ive tried that and it just doesn't work. Do you know any other method i could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example i use some JS to alter the css. 
The button i added changes the css of the header with ID 'header'.
But you could just change the display:grid to display:none.

```js
function hideheader(){
  document.getElementById("header").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
header {
    height: 53px;
    width: 53px;
    background-color: black;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 118px 244px 118px;

    padding-top: 3px;

    font-size: 45px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.headerBox {
    background-color: #4472C4;
}

.leftDrive {
    background-color: black;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
    grid-column-gap: 3px; 

    padding-inline-start: 3px;
    padding-inline-end: 4px;

}

.battery {
    background-color: #4472C4;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
}

.rightDrive {
    background-color: black;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
    grid-column-gap: 3px; 

    padding-inline-start: 4px;
    padding-inline-end: 3px;
}
```

```html
<header id="header"> 
    <div class="leftDrive">
        <div class="headerBox" id="l_motor">0</div>
        <div class="headerBox" id="l_inverter">0</div>
    </div>
    <div class="battery">
        <div class="headerBox" id="battery_1">0</div>
        <div class="headerBox" id="battery_2">0</div>
        <div class="headerBox" id="battery_3">0</div>
        <div class="headerBox" id="battery_4">0</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightDrive">
        <div class="headerBox" id="r_inverter">0</div>
        <div class="headerBox" id="r_motor">0</div>
    </div>
</header>

<button onclick="hideheader()">hide</button>
```

Comment: Please write some explanation of what your code is doing and how it solves the issue. Code-only answers are discouraged.

Comment: noted.. i get the discouragement, but really.. i'm with @Lennholm on this...